# REST Service returns HTTP 204 (Tomcat/Linux)

Tags: java, web-services, rest, tomcat, jersey

I have a problem running my code on a linux distribution (Raspbian, Tomcat 7). The problem doesn't appear in the test environment under Windows/Tomcat 7/Eclipse:

My webservice just returns HTTP 204 and nothing else. The log doesn't contain any indication that there was an error during the request. It should, as it does in the test environment, respond with a json.

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
version="3.0">
<display-name>***</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<listener>
    <listener-class>**.useravailability.UserAvailabilityServletContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/REST/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.servlet.ServletAdaptor</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

</web-app>
```

usersService.xml

```
package **.webservice;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import com.google.gson.Gson;

import **.model.AccessManager;

@Path("/usersService")
public class UsersService {
@GET
@Produces("application/json")
public String getUser() {       
    String user = null;
    ArrayList<String> userList = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {       
        userList = new AccessManager().getUser();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        user = gson.toJson(userList);           
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return user;
}


}
```

What am I missing? And why does it work in the test environment?
Thank you!

Comment: Can you show us how you're invoking the web service from the client side?  HTTP 204 means the request was fine and the server processed it correctly, but there is no content to return after the headers.  Maybe you're requesting a content type other than application/json? [http codes and meanings](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)

Comment: Thank you for your answer:
I use POSTMAN, a REST Client. Headers are: Content-Type: application/json; Accept: application/json.
The result is empty.

Comment: Is it possible that there is an exception and null is returned, but the stacktrace is not getting into your logfile?

Comment: can you try returning something in the catch block? try return "string for test"; and test again...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all!
I missed a error message, that there was the jdbc driver missing.
I forgot to add it to the build path before the upload.

Answer (score 5):

Jersey returns an HTTP 204 if you return null.

I consider this the best behavior possible.

In your case, you probably have an exception raised, so user is null.

if you want to return an error code (which might be more logical) you can replace

```
catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

by

```
catch (Exception e) {
        throw new WebApplicationException(404);
    }
```

if you want to state that the user could not be found, or a 5XX HTTp if you want to return a server side error code.